# Why doesn't this javascript code work with the html5 (saving an ordered list in local storage)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a unordered list in HTML and I want it so that the content is editable and saves locally, so that when you refresh the edited list is there instead of the default one.

HTML:

```
<ul id="items" contenteditable="true">
    <li> Read up on HTML</li>
    <li> Learn new things in HTML5</li>
    <li> Try testing my knowledge by building a mobile app</li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
    var items = document.getElementById('items');
    $(items).blur(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('itemData', this.innerHTML);
    });
    if(localStorage.getItem('itemData')) {
        items.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('itemData');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is working for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/kkVMv/

Answer (score 1):

That code does work after blurring the element. Maybe this would work better with the `keyup` event.

```
$(items).keyup(function () {
    localStorage.setItem('itemData', this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by blurring the element(i'm new and don't know much about blurring)?

Comment: The blur event occurs when a focusable element loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm new and might be totally missing the point.  But in the code you posted you didn't refresh the list.  When I was making a dynamic list I put the refresh in the function that makes the list.  eg   $(items).listview('refresh');

Comment: I'm not refreshing the list but just giving a saved list if there was one.

Comment: You don't need to refresh this kind of list..?